# 2D Game engine for android

Tags: java, android

I am new on 2D Game development in android  . I Heard about AndEngine, but i dont know how to use this . Please Help me

Help Will be Appriciated

Comment: not a good question. please add more info. 2d or 3d game? https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion rather than answers. Don't ask about ; Product or service recommendations or comparisons, Requests for lists of things, polls, opinions, discussions, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only used one of them and below its specialities(supports android) as I remember. Others which I dont know about:

[Jogre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jogre) -->I dont know if this supports Android, but trying does not hurt

[env3D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Env3D) --> Supports android.

[jake2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jake2) -->I dont know if this supports Android

[jpct](http://www.jpct.net/) ---> Supports for android.

[LWJGL](http://www.lwjgl.org/) --->a good base

You can access the [Jmonkey Engine 3.0](http://jmonkeyengine.org/) to add it to your Eclipse projects or to just create scenes from ground up with its sdk.

You can do many things easily with its already-invented classes. You can apply many types of physics(event driven or time step), raytracing, building a 3D world with 3D object static or dynamically alterable. You can build custom shapes, even importing from manyfile types is made easy. You just need some time to create your game.

If you need custom mass-physics then you will need good opengl wisdom or opencl-cuda.

Jmonkey's engine lets you choose full-screen or windowed frame; anti aliasing(?X) or not; every resolution available; custom fps limiter; overridable simpleUpdate() and overridable simpleRender() methods to change 3D realm before it gets drawn.

There are types of light and shadow classes. Point light, spot light, directional light and appropriate shadow-casters of these. Also jmonkey supports Android.

Comment: -1 Is this an advertisement or an answer?

Comment: Alright. Forgot to add other options :D

Comment: answering a questions that are primarily opinion-based is not way of stackoverflow. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500724/2d-game-engine-for-android#comment25440402_17500724
So still -1.

Comment: To be able to stay objective?